# Fulltext search not working properly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have pers table and applied combine fulltext index on (prenom, nom) fields. Below are data in that table.

```
persID prenom      nom (pers table)
--------------------------------
 116    te          te
 117    te test     test te
```

Now, I tried to fetch above record using **MATCH and AGAINST**. Below is my query.

```
SELECT `Pers`.`persID`, Pers.prenom, Pers.nom
FROM `bdrplus`.`pers` AS `Pers`
LEFT JOIN `bdrplus`.`pers_detail` AS `PersDetail` 
     ON ( `PersDetail`.`persID` = `Pers`.`persID` )
WHERE `Pers`.`etat` =1
AND `Pers`.`persID` !=55
AND MATCH(`Pers`.`prenom`, `Pers`.`nom`) AGAINST('te*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Result
------------------------
persID   prenom      nom     
117     te test     test te
```

Now I tried using mysql **LIKE(%..%)** operator. Below is the query which I tried.

```
SELECT `Pers`.`persID`
FROM `bdrplus`.`pers` AS `Pers`
LEFT JOIN `bdrplus`.`pers_detail` AS `PersDetail` 
     ON ( `PersDetail`.`persID` = `Pers`.`persID` )
WHERE `Pers`.`etat` =1
AND `Pers`.`persID` !=55
AND (Pers.prenom LIKE 'te%' OR Pers.nom LIKE 'te%')

Result
-----------------------
 persID prenom      nom (pers table)
 116    te          te
 117    te test     test te
```

I don't understand why I am not getting both records using MATCH AGAINST operator in fulltext index query?

Comment: If the table InnoDB or MyISAM ?

Answer (score 1):

By default MySQL uses ft_min_word_len=3 setting which tell MySQL full-text engine to ignore all the words LESS than 3 letters. You need to decrease this variable. It's not dynamic so you may need to restart MySQL. However setting it to less than 3 may affect performance.